# React Axios PUT/PATCH method Unauthorized, laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, react, axios

Os métodos PUT/PATCH disponíveis na API através da função `Route::apiResource('user','UserController');` são esses:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As requisições GET e POST funcionam normalmente, porém na implementação da rota PUT/PATCH eu recebo a mensagem "Unauthorized" da API:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo ao utilizar um cliente REST como postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo obter acesso a rota, logo acredito que minha requisição axios esteja errada:

```
let header = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `${this.state.tokenType} ${this.state.token}`
  }
}
var body = new FormData();
body.append('canAddAdm', this.state.canAddAdm);
body.append('canAddUser', this.state.canAddUser);
body.append('canAddStructures', this.state.canAddStructures);
Axios.put(`${this.state.url}/api/user/{${this.state.selectedOption}}`, header, body)
  .then(res => res.data)
    .then(result => {
      console.log('result :', result);
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error when update user: ', error.response);
  })
}
```

Então minha pergunta é, o que eu estaria fazendo de errado para conseguir acessar o método update do Laravel via Axios?

Comment: Provavelmente é erro de Cors... Antes do request propriamente dito o navegador manda uma requisição OPTIONS, você precisa aceitar esse tipo de requisição na rua rota no backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja por causa da ordem que você está passando os argumentos para o Axios. Se você olhar a API, vai ver que a chamada do put é da seguinte maneira: `axios.put(url[, data[, config]])`

Ou seja, sua chamada deveria ser:

```
Axios.put(`${this.state.url}/api/user/{${this.state.selectedOption}}`, body, header)
   .then(...)
   .catch(...)
```

Comment: Ai ai, apanhar para um erro desses... O jeito é sair e tomar um café pra respirar um pouco... Muito obrigado, eu tava caçando encrenca achando que tinha algo errado com o conteúdo de header e body e não com a ordem como eles eram passados!